# PHP restrict the output size of exec()

Tags: php, exec

I am using PHP exec() function to execute a c code. Sometimes the output of the code exceeds php memory limit and it throws PHP Fatal Error. Is there any way I can restrict the output size, or the array size passed to exec() so that any output beyond N chars is ignored.

I have tried catching Fatal Error using register_shutdown_function() but it doesn't seem to work. Any other solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can either redirect the output to a file (e.g. append `> output.log` to the command) and read how much content you need from that file once `exec()` is done, or you can use `proc_open()` instead and a stream for output and read only some of the stream's content when the execution finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when i try to get the output of CURL, but the output was not complete.

When i used `shell_exec` it doesn't have limit on output and return the full output

For example:

```
$output = shell_exec('curl -k -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8000/services"');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

You can read more on php documentation [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)